# Error serving multiple PHP files on app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, appengine-magic

I'm having issues serving a PHP app on Google app engine. It works, but there are some files (like css and images) that aren't displaying.

Assuming I have a web application in a folder of the nature displayed below:

```
|_admin
|   |_images
|   |   |_admImage.png
|   |_index.php
|   |_dashboard.php
|_includes
|  |_connection.php
|_styles
|   |_css
|   |   |_style.css
|   |_js
|   |   |_scripts.js
|   |_img
|   |   |_favicon.ico
|   |_ |_welcome.gif
|_book_imgs
|  |_book1.jpeg
|_users
|   |_images
|   |   |_passport.jpeg
|   |   |_index.php
|   |_ |_books.php
|_index.php
|_books.php
```

The `connection.php` file in the includes folder is linked to every single `.php` file in every folder. It connects the individual pages to the database.
The stylesheets and images (such as favicon) from the **style folder** also connects to every single page.

If I'm to publish on Google app engine, what should the `app.yaml` file look like?

Comment: What's your current `app.yaml` file?

Comment: It only carried .* on "urls"